# How to train only one column instead of all columns?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I was working on the Boston Housing problem for convolutional neural network. At the begining I just tried to solve the usual problem, but I read in somewhere that I should try to train only one attribute at time.
In the first problem I was able to solve it (training all attributes at same time). I was requested to create an convolutional neural network.
The second problem is the same but only one attribute must be trained at time.

Here is the first solution:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import tensorflow.keras
import sklearn as sk
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense



from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)
tensorflow.random.set_seed(2)



boston_housing = keras.datasets.boston_housing

boston_housing
boston_housing.load_data()

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = boston_housing.load_data()
train_data.shape , train_labels.shape, test_data.shape, test_labels.shape

type(train_data)

order = np.argsort(np.random.random(train_labels.shape))
train_data = train_data[order]
train_labels = train_labels[order]


column_names = ['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD','TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT']
df = pd.DataFrame(train_data, columns=column_names)

mean = train_data.mean(axis=0)
std = train_data.std(axis=0)
train_data = (train_data - mean) / std
test_data = (test_data - mean) / std
print(train_data[0])




from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense


def build_model():

    
    input = Input(shape=(train_data.shape[1],))
    
    hidden1 = Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu)(input)
    hidden2 = Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu)(hidden1)
    
    output = Dense(1)(hidden2)
    
    model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output, name="RNA_Boston_Housing")
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae']) # mae: mean absolute error
    return model

model = build_model()
model.summary()

class PrintDot(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
        if epoch % 100 == 0: print('') # % :Divides left hand operand by right hand operand and returns remainder
        print('.', end='')
        
EPOCHS = 500
# Armazena as estatisticas do treinamento
historia1 = model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=EPOCHS,

validation_split=0.2, verbose=0,
callbacks=[PrintDot()])

historia1.history


def plot_history(history):
    plt.figure()
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel('Mean Abs Error [$1000]')
    plt.plot(history.epoch, np.array(history.history['mae']), label='Mean Absolute Error')
    plt.plot(history.epoch, np.array(history.history['val_mae']), label = 'Val Mean Absolute Error') # Val. : Validation
    plt.legend()
    plt.ylim([0, 5])
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]=(10,6)
    
plot_history(historia1)



[loss, mae] = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels, verbose=0)
print("Mean Absuto Error para o Conjunto de Teste: ${:7.2f}".format(mae * 1000)
```

And i got stucked in the second one:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import tensorflow.keras
import sklearn as sk
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense



from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)
tensorflow.random.set_seed(2)



boston_housing = keras.datasets.boston_housing

boston_housing
boston_housing.load_data()

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = boston_housing.load_data()
train_data.shape , train_labels.shape, test_data.shape, test_labels.shape


train_data = df['CRIM']
print(train_data)


order = np.argsort(np.random.random(train_labels.shape))
train_data = train_data[order]
train_labels = train_labels[order]


column_names = ['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD','TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT']
df = pd.DataFrame(train_data, columns=column_names)

mean = train_data.mean(axis=0)
std = train_data.std(axis=0)
train_data = (train_data - mean) / std
test_data = (test_data - mean) / std
print(train_data[0])

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense


def build_model():

   
    input = Input(shape=(train_data.shape[1],))
    
    hidden1 = Dense(32, activation=tf.nn.relu)(input)
    hidden2 = Dense(32, activation=tf.nn.relu)(hidden1)
   
    output = Dense(1)(hidden2)
 
    
    model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output, name="RNA_Boston_Housing")
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.002)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae']) # mae: mean absolute error
    return model

model = build_model()
model.summary()
```

Followed by the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3444, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18228/2159887969.py", line 69, in <module>
    model = build_model()
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18228/2159887969.py", line 56, in build_model
    input = Input(shape=(train_data.shape[1],))
IndexError: tuple index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2064, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'IndexError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1101, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 248, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 281, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'
ERROR! Session/line number was not unique in database. History logging moved to new session 96
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3444, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18228/2159887969.py", line 69, in <module>
    model = build_model()
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18228/2159887969.py", line 56, in build_model
    input = Input(shape=(train_data.shape[1],))
IndexError: tuple index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2064, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'IndexError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3364, in run_ast_nodes
    if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3461, in run_code
    self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2067, in showtraceback
    value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1368, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1268, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1125, in structured_traceback
    tb_offset)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1082, in format_exception_as_a_whole
    last_unique, recursion_repeat = find_recursion(orig_etype, evalue, records)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 382, in find_recursion
    return len(records), 0
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2064, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1101, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 248, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 281, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3444, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18228/2159887969.py", line 69, in <module>
    model = build_model()
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18228/2159887969.py", line 56, in build_model
    input = Input(shape=(train_data.shape[1],))
IndexError: tuple index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2064, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'IndexError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3364, in run_ast_nodes
    if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3461, in run_code
    self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2067, in showtraceback
    value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1368, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1268, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1125, in structured_traceback
    tb_offset)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1082, in format_exception_as_a_whole
    last_unique, recursion_repeat = find_recursion(orig_etype, evalue, records)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 382, in find_recursion
    return len(records), 0
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2064, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2947, in _run_cell
    return runner(coro)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
    coro.send(None)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3173, in run_cell_async
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3383, in run_ast_nodes
    self.showtraceback()
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2067, in showtraceback
    value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1368, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1268, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1143, in structured_traceback
    chained_exceptions_tb_offset)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1082, in format_exception_as_a_whole
    last_unique, recursion_repeat = find_recursion(orig_etype, evalue, records)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 382, in find_recursion
    return len(records), 0
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2064, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1101, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 248, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 281, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\Leonardo\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'
```

Comment: pip install tensorflow-estimator?

Comment: selected_columns = df[['CRIM']]

Answer (score 0):

To select one column in the dataset, you can modify code as below and run the program again:

```
#train_data = df['CRIM']
#print(train_data)

train_data=train_data[:,0:1]
print(train_data.shape[1])

test_data=test_data[:,0:1]
print(train_data.shape[1])

column_names = ['CRIM'] #, 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD','TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT']
df = pd.DataFrame(train_data, columns=column_names)
df.head()
```